# Don't see special font characters in run.text (sometimes)

Tags: python-docx

I have a word document mixing some Wingdings characters with Cambria text. When I look into the runs, I see sometimes a run.text with length 1 and the character is in hex e.g. 0xf063. The run.font.name is e.g. Wingdings 2. This is as expected. But often I see an empty run.text (font name still Wingdings). Nevertheless, the characters must be there, because, when I append the run to a new paragraph, I can see them in Word, at least when I pass them just through. When I however duplicate the run (as best as I can), the characters are lost, probably, because, when I dup the run, I miss something. So my question is, where are the characters stored when run.text is empty, and what do I have to observe when I duplicate such a run.
The characters are not lost during run duplication, however, if the run.text is not empty. Thus, the problem originates when the document is read, and sometimes the character is in run.text, and sometimes somewhere else. Which one is unpredictable to me.

I just had the idea to unzip the doc and look into document.xml. There I see

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00946796"> 
  <w:rPr> <w:color w:val="EE9512"/> 
    <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/> 
  </w:rPr> 
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">YYYYYYY 
  </w:t> 
</w:r> 
<w:r w:rsidR="009E034B" w:rsidRPr="00695B07"> 
  <w:rPr> 
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Wingdings 3" w:hAnsi="Wingdings 3"/> 
    <w:color w:val="EE9512"/> 
  </w:rPr> 
  <w:sym w:font="Wingdings 2" w:char="F038"/> 
</w:r>
```

So when run.text is empty, the chars are in a w:sym element, else in a w:t element.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the special character as a "symbol" here:

```xml
<w:r w:rsidR="009E034B" w:rsidRPr="00695B07"> 
  <w:rPr> 
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Wingdings 3" w:hAnsi="Wingdings 3"/> 
    <w:color w:val="EE9512"/> 
  </w:rPr> 
  <w:sym w:font="Wingdings 2" w:char="F038"/>  <!-- <<==== this line -->
</w:r>
```

I haven't researched this in depth, but I expect the distinction here is that the *glyphs* in this "font" are not stylized versions of the unicode codepoint at which they appear.

For example, there are no "A", "B", "C" characters in this font, those positions are taken by arrows or something instead.

I imagine the distinction is important because you couldn't get good results by substituting a similar font if Windings 2 is not installed on the current machine. So at least that font-substitution behavior would be different for this symbol than for regular characters.

There is no API support yet for symbols in runs, so you'd need to use `lxml` calls to access these elements, perhaps something like:

```py
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

syms = run._r.xpath("./w:sym")
for sym in syms:
    print("font == %s" % sym.get(qn("w:font")))
    print("char == %s" % sym.get(qn("w:char")))
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours I think I see the complete picture. First, as scanny wrote above, python-docx does not handle w:sym elements at all (yet?), so these are lost after reading the docx, unless you resort to lxml. Then, why do I sometimes see a Wingdings character in w:t, sometimes in w:sym? Well, if I use the Word Symbol chooser (a window with all the characters in a font, where you can select one and then press "Insert" at the bottom), then you get a w:sym element. If you just set the font to Wingdings, and then type the suitable character on the keyboard (e.g. an 8 for a Wingdings 2 Circle with Dot inside), then you get a w:t element.
Thus I managed to remove all w:sym elements. To determine the "suitable" character, google for "Wingdings translator".